# Math.Round() call in .NET using negative precision

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have a requirement to perform rounding of values with negative precision. As far as I've checked, `Math.Round()` in .NET does *not* support negative precision.  For example:

```
ROUND(43.34566,-1)
```

The above returns 40.

Please suggest how to achive this.

Comment: divide by 10, round, multiply by 10

Comment: Negative precision is really just a convention of languages/libraries that support rounding to the nearest 10, 100, etc. Try searching for what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks sashkello. This is working fine even I've adopted same technique,how can we go for generic implementation. Here precision is -1 it might change with diffrent cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the comma to the precision you want to give back and then round.

```
        double n = 43.34566;
        double roundingValue = -1;
        double precision = Math.Pow(10, roundingValue);
        n *= precision;
        double result  = Math.Round(n, 0) / precision;
```

Answer (score 1):

ROUND(43.34566 / 10,0) * 10 will work; generalise as appropriate.

Comment: ROUND(43.34566 / 10,0) * 10

Comment: @sashkello, touche! I've amended; better get that coffee...

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple really:

```
Math.Round(num / Math.Pow(10.0, -(precision))) * Math.Pow(10.0, -(precision));
//this won't work for positives but oh well
```

Comment: Because you probably mean 10 to the power of precision. Then it'll work...

Comment: @sashkello Yep, fixed.